# How to add youtube channel to wowza

Tags: javascript, youtube, wowza

Every One!
I'm new to wowza.
I already set up wowza streaming engine.
Now i am able to play the sample.mp4 file from the test app given by wowza.

Now I'm going to stream youtube videos with wowza.
youtube->wowza

Is it possible?
Can you give me some solution?

Comment: does youtube allow you to do this/

Comment: Hello, Jaromanda.
What do you mean?
Isn't it possible?

Comment: there's a difference between what can't be done and what you are not allowed to do

Answer (score 0):

YouTube streams are usually only accessible through HTTP protocol, and unfortunately, Wowza currently does not allow ingesting an HTTP stream. You can send your stream from Wowza to YouTube (Wowza -> YouTube), but not the other way around.

Comment: thank you for your reply.
How about using Media Cache?

Comment: MediaCache can be used to query VOD assets that are served from a web server, such as IIS or Apache, and usually takes the form of `http://webserverhost/path/to/file.mp4`. YouTube videos are really VOD streams (either Flash-based or HTML5), much like how you would stream VOD files from a Wowza server.